# Call WHMCS $_SESSION['uid'] from external domain?

Tags: php, authentication, whmcs

So I am working with WHMCS, I have my main site at www.hoststratus.com. My WHMCS installation is on https://clients.hoststratus.com, I am trying to setup an external login from the main site. For some reason I can not pickup the session UID. No PHP errors present. Is this even possible from an external domain without the SSL cert, etc.? Also, in case you aren't familiar with WHMCS and wonder where the session comes from, it's being generated from dbconnect.php.

```
 <?php 
require("clients/dbconnect.php"); 
 if ($_SESSION['uid']) {
echo "Welcome, you are logged in."; 
 } else { ?>
    <div id="login-popup">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="cabf6fe8fb6b2d4b47486809832256bff4865fed" />
    <span class="login-pop-up-icon"></span><div>Client Login</div>
    <form  action="https://clients.hoststratus.com/dologin.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="email address" name="username" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <div><a href="https://clients.hoststratus.com/pwreset.php">forgot password?</a></div>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing  :http://docs.whmcs.com/Creating_Pages

You can get the session ID of the user as :

```
 require("init.php");

 $ca = new WHMCS_ClientArea();

 $userid = $ca->getUserID() ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I tried to use the example code provided in the docs, it forced you to use the Smarty templating system, which I did not want to do. This code does not require you to use Smarty.

Comment: By "the session ID of the user" we mean "the uid of the user from the session", I believe ...